# How to install methylKit package in R version 3.2.3

Tags: r, installation, r-package

I am trying to install methylKit package in R version 3.2.3 .
When I install this package it gives error

```
biocLite("methylKit, lib="")
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘methykit/’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

shall I have to really upgrade R version??
Please reply as I am very confused regarding this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `devtools::install_github("al2na/methylKit", build_vignettes=FALSE, repos=BiocInstaller::biocinstallRepos(), dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: Not worked .  ERROR: this R is version 3.2.3, package 'methylKit' requires R >= 3.3.0
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("methylKit")
```

Comment: Not worked Warning message:
package ‘methylKit’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)

Comment: As mentioned on the [Bioconductor page](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/methylKit.html), this package requires R 3.3.0. You will have to update your R version.

Comment: Thank you so much @DCZ. I will try with this.

Comment: How to update R for R 3.3.0 version. could you plz share?

Comment: Just go to [CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/) and select the correct version for your OS.